# Getting an error about variable not existing in current context

Tags: c#, variables

I have written out a program that declares an array of 10 integers, takes input from the user and puts them in the array and then accepts out parameters for the highest value, lowest value, sum of all values, and the average.

The main method displays all the stats. I don't know why, but I get the error

> k does not exist in the current context - line 51 column 5

when I have previously declared it before that given line. Any help would be appreciated.

```
using System;

namespace IntegerStatistics
{    
   class Program
   {
       static void Main()
       {
           Console.Clear();
           // Declaring variables
           int[] userArray = FillArray();
           int ArrayHighest = 0;
           int ArrayLowest = 0;
           int ArraySum = 0;
           int ArrayAverage = 0;
           Calculations(userArray, out ArrayHighest, out ArrayLowest, out ArraySum, out ArrayAverage);

           Console.WriteLine("The lowest value in the array is {0}, while the highest is {1}.", ArrayLowest, ArrayHighest);
           Console.WriteLine("The array has a sum of {0} and averages out to {1}.", ArraySum, ArrayAverage);

           Console.ReadLine();
       }
       private static int[] FillArray()
       {
           int[] intArray = new int[10];
           int numbersEntered = 0;
           int intTemp = 0;
           string strTemp = "";
           for(int k = 0; k < 10; ++k)
           {
               Console.WriteLine("Enter a whole number or 999 to quit:  ");
               strTemp = Console.ReadLine();
               while(!int.TryParse(strTemp, out intTemp))
               {
                   Console.WriteLine("Input was not in the correct format");

                   Console.Write("Please enter a valid number:  ");
                   strTemp = Console.ReadLine();
               }
           }
           if(intTemp != 999)
           {
               intArray[k] = intTemp;
               ++numbersEntered;
           }
           else
           {
               k = 10;
           }
           Array.Resize(ref intArray, numbersEntered);
           return intArray;
       }
       private static void Calculations(int[] intArray, out int Highest, out int Lowest, out int intSum, out int average)
       {
           intSum = 0;
           Array.Sort(intArray);
           Lowest = intArray[0];
           Array.Reverse(intArray);
           Highest = intArray[0];
           Array.Reverse(intArray);
           for(int k = 0; k < intArray.Length; ++k)
           {
               intSum += intArray[k];
           }
           average = intSum / intArray.Length;
       }
    }
 }
```

The line I'm specifically having issues with is:

```
if (intTemp != 999)
{
    intArray[k] = intTemp;
    ++numbersEntered;
}
else
{
    k = 10;
}
```

Comment: `k` is your temp loop iterator.  it doesnt exist outside that loop

Comment: You need to put your `if-else` inside the `for` loop.

Comment: okay, I moved my bracket and then I get the error `Unreachable code detected`

Comment: do a C# `MSDN` search on the key word `Scope` once you understand scope you will not run into this type of error in the future

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to place the if-else block inside the for-loop.

Since you want to check if the input number is 999 for each iteration, you could write your for-loop like this:

```
for(int k = 0; k < 10; ++k)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a whole number or 999 to quit:  ");
    strTemp = Console.ReadLine();
    while(!int.TryParse(strTemp, out intTemp))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Input was not in the correct format");

        Console.Write("Please enter a valid number:  ");
        strTemp = Console.ReadLine();
    }

    if(intTemp != 999)
    {
        intArray[k] = intTemp;
        ++numbersEntered;
    }
    else
    {
        k = 10;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The loop variable `k` goes out of scope when the code leaves the `for` loop. So, you can use variable `k` only within the loop.

So, you need to move your `if-else` inside your `for` loop. Change your `FillArray()` method to

```
private static int[] FillArray()
{
    int[] intArray = new int[10];
    int numbersEntered = 0;
    int intTemp = 0;
    string strTemp = "";
    for (int k = 0; k < 10; ++k)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a whole number or 999 to quit:  ");
        strTemp = Console.ReadLine();
        while (!int.TryParse(strTemp, out intTemp))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Input was not in the correct format");
            Console.Write("Please enter a valid number:  ");
            strTemp = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        if (intTemp != 999)
        {
            intArray[k] = intTemp;
            ++numbersEntered;
        }
        else
            break;
    }
    Array.Resize(ref intArray, numbersEntered);
    return intArray;
}
```

Also, I'd suggest changing `ArrayAverage` to double type. e.g. 2, 3 => average 2.5

```
double ArrayAverage = 0; //average need not be whole number
```

Additionally, with `Linq` you can shorten your `Calculations` method as

```
//using System.Linq;
private static void Calculations(int[] intArray, out int Highest, out int Lowest, out int intSum, out double average)
{
    Lowest = intArray.Min();
    Highest = intArray.Max();
    intSum = intArray.Sum();
    average = intArray.Average();
}
```